# Al insertar formulario, no se inserta ruta de archivo

Tags: php, mysqli

presento el siguiente error al momento de seleccionar un archivo y subirlo al servidor, estoy trabajando localmente y por medio de un formulario dos botones, uno para seleccionar el archivo a subir y el otro para enviar a la base de datos el código esta en PHP y la base de datos es en MySql, el formulario funciona de maravillas solo hasta cuando doy clic en el boton subir que es el que hace el insert. Este es el error que aparece, agradezco mucho si me pueden asesorar.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\archivo.php on line 18
ERROR: error DB.
No Se Puede Ejecutar La Consulta:
select*from libro1 where id_documento=
MySql Tipo De Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Código "index.php"

```
<?php
include_once 'config.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" .$nombre;
    if ($nombre != "") {
        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO libro1(titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$titulo','$descri','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')";
            $query = $db->execute($sql);
            if($query){
                echo "Se guardo correctamente";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 500px;margin: auto;border: 1px solid blue;padding: 30px;">
            <h4>Subir PDF</h4>
            <form method="post" action="archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Titulo</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="titulo"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Descripcion</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="descripcion"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="archivo[]" multiple></td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="subir" name="subir"></td>
                        <td><a href="lista.php">lista</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indicas en la pregunta que el código PHP se corresponde con index.php, pero el error se da en la página archivo.php y se produce en una consulta SELECT que no aparece en el extracto que has pegado. Por otro lado en el insert, tratas tamanio como un String, ¿es correcto eso? Y por último, échale un ojo a los PreparedStatement para evitar inyecciones SQL.

Comment: Disculpa, tuve un error, el archivo que hace el insert es el mismo index.php, ya modifique el acction, y el error que aparece es: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\index.php on line 14

Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\index.php on line 16
Error

Comment: Cuando tu código falle usa `var_dump` para verificar el elemento erróneo. Para este caso interesa ver el resultado de `var_dump($_FILES);` todo parece indicar que en `$ruta` hay un array, no una cadena.

Comment: Haciendo el var_dump($_FILES); aparece este error en index.php: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\index.php on line 14

Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\index.php on line 16.
Errorarray(1) { ["archivo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "Pagina prueba.html" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "text/html" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php5ECE.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(152344) } } }